# source file as an argument?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I've read up on using source to run another file inside another:

```
source ./filename
```

but I want to do this inside a command as an argument.. (or set of)

Here is how the command goes:

```
command \
-argument \
-argument \
source ./file
-argument \
...
```

The file would basically contain a set of other arguments:

```
-argument \
-argument \
```

How do I do this? running it as is, would make the command fail..

Comment: Do you want the output of `./file` to be treated as an argument to `command`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you want the contents of `filename` as arguments. This can be done easily, if your arguments do not have whitespace or globbing operators:

```
command \
-argument \
-argument \
$(cat ./file) \
-argument \
...
```

If your arguments don't contain newlines, or some other character, then you could use that character as a delimiter and construct the argument list:

```
#! /bin/bash
args=()
while IFS= read -r arg
do
    args+=("$arg")
done < filename
command \
-argument \
-argument \
"${args[@]}" \
-argument \
...
```

If say, the arguments don't contain `|`, then you could instead do:

```
while IFS= read -d'|' -r arg
```

Where the file contains:

```
-arg1 something|-arg2
something else|-arg3 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
command \
-argument \
-argument \
$(cat ./file) \
-argument \
...
```

would work with

```
-argument 
-argument
```

or

```
-argument -argument
```

as `./file`.
The shell will split it on `$IFS` (tab, newline, space by default) if the `$(cat ./file)` is left bare, without double quotes.

An alternative where you wouldn't need to remove the slashes could be to construct a string and then `eval` it.